# Implementing URL Versioning without using any 3rd party plugin like UrlRewrite

Tags: java, rest, jersey, versioning

I have a requirement where i have to implement URL versioning. SO my REST URL should work both with version inside the url and without version in url. In case if no version is mentioned in URL then API will be redirected to the latest version.

Eg.

`http://localhost:9090/v1/myservice/listAll` should call version 1 of my API and if i use url  `http://localhost:9090/myservice/listAll` then it should point to the latest version of  API.Lets say if i don't mention V1 in URL then it should also point to `http://localhost:9090/v1/myservice/listAll`. So its a kind of Version and VersionLess URL.

I am using Jersey for implementing my REST API and already done versioning using UrlRewrite but according to the requirement i cannot use any 3rd party API.

So what is the way withing Jersey to implement such functionality?

Can i do this with @Path annotation and define Multiple URL's for same resource?

*Note: I know that URL versioning is not a good way to implement
versioning rather i should have used custom headers for versioning.
But here i have strict requirement from client to implement versioning
using in URL only !*

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
@Path("/myService")
public class MyLatestService {

    @GET
    @Path("listAll")
    public Response getMyService(...) { /* call the latest version */ }

}

@Path("/v1/myService")
public class MyV1Service {

    @GET
    @Path("listAll")
    public Response getMyService(...) { ... }

}

@Path("/v2/myService")
public class MyV2Service {

    @GET
    @Path("listAll")
    public Response getMyService(...) { ... }

}
```

and so on..

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i guess using this way can make so much of duplicate in every method. Also if the versions keep on increasing then it will keep on increasing the size of my class also.Though versioning itself is a mess of managing code for each version.

Answer (score 0):

You can use optional path parameters like this:

```
/* Handle v1 explicitly and implicitly */
@Path("/{version: v1/}?myService")
public class MyServiceV1 {
  @GET
  @Path("listAll")
  public Response listAll(){}
}

/* Handle v2 explicitly */
@Path("/v2/myService")
public class MyServiceV1 {
  @GET
  @Path("listAll")
  public Response listAll(){}
}
```